# Is there a way to customize/move the "Unsubscribe" message and link of an Amazon SNS message to the bottom of the page?

Tags: alert, customization, amazon-sns, unsubscribe, list-unsubscribe

I want to move the "Unsubscribe" and AWS FAQ links in Cloudwatch alerts/sns messages to the bottom of the page. Is there a way to customize/move the "Unsubscribe" message and link of an Amazon SNS message to the bottom of the page?

I did not try anything yet, as I am hearing that there is no way to do it. Please prove them wrong.

Comment: No, there is no capability to modify/remove this message. If it is not suitable for your needs, then perhaps you should consider using Amazon SES to send messages. This would, of course, require an architectural change.